# how to create a text box when button is pressed in Js?

Tags: javascript, html, button, textbox

I want to create a button in JS and when you press it, it will create a text box above the button. But the number of textboxes is unknown.
is it possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ronak</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="textboxContainer">
  </div>
  <button onclick="addTextbox(event)">Click Me!</button>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addTextbox(event) {
          var input = document.createElement("input");
          input.setAttribute("type", "text");
          document.getElementById("textboxContainer").appendChild(input);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are one way. You have to append it. With Jquery it is something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button></button>
    <p id="new"></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>    
$("button").click(()=>{
    $("p#new").append("Your input textbox<input ---/>")
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```